# Ctrl+Alt+L and new blank lines in IntelliJ Idea 12

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, ide

Intelli J Idea 12 inserts new blank lines between members of a class whenever I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in Scala projects. For instance:

```
class Class1 {
  private val val1 = ...
  private def def1 = ....
  private def def2 = ...
}
```

will become

```
class Class1 {
  private val val1 = ...

  private def def1 = ....

  private def def2 = ...
}
```

How do I make it not to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is controlled by the following code style setting (`Blank Lines` | `Around Method`):

[image: around method]

Comment: it's in "Project setting". Do I have to set it for every new project?

Comment: It's set per code style Scheme name. If you use the same code style scheme in other projects, you don't have to configure it again.

Comment: However, in case there are some extra blank lines, Ctrl+Alt+L doesn't remove them; it appends a new line if needed but it doesn't remove extra ones if they exist. What do I do about it?

Comment: @MariusKavansky It's controlled by the `Keep Maximum Blank Lines` settings.